# AJAX call using the last variable loaded on the page instead of current post

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm creating a custom plugin that fires a ajax call when they sharing the post on twitter, Google + or liking it on Facebook.

Within the index.php file I put this inside the loop so it gets called on every new post on the home page.

```
<?php cp_social_sharing_4pts(); ?>
```

Here part of my PHP function:

```
function cp_social_sharing_4pts(){
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">
 var postid = '.get_the_ID().';
 function cp_share_twitter_do(){
 jQuery.ajax({dataType: "json", data: {action: "cp_share_twitter_do", post: postid},
  success: function(data){
  if(data.success==true){
  Boxy.alert(data.message);
  thebox.hide();
  thebox.unload();
 } else { Boxy.alert(data.message); }
 }
 });
}
</script>
';
}
 // Show Buttons
 echo 'Post ID: '.get_the_ID().'<br />'; // debug
echo '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-    url="'.get_permalink().'" data-text="'.get_the_title().'" data-count="horizontal" data-     via="ps3blogdotnet">Tweet</a>'; 
}
```

Then this gets loaded into the head:

```
function cp_social_sharing_js(){
 if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo '
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
twttr.events.bind(\'tweet\', function(event) { cp_share_twitter_do(); });
</script>
';
 }  
}
add_action('wp_head','cp_social_sharing_js');
```

After the AJAX fires it goes here:

```
    function cp_share_twitter_do(){ // Tweet Entry
            $cp_postID = $_POST['post']; // THIS IS THE ISSUE. It's not returning the correct ID from the post I shared on.
    // Do more functions here
    echo json_encode($r);
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_cp_share_twitter_do', 'cp_share_twitter_do');
```

This does work perfectly if on a single blog post. The issue is on the home page.

The variable **postid** does correctly display the post ID on each post. But when the ajax call completes it always passes the post id of the last post displayed on the home page instead of the current post.

Comment: You really really need to look into using [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)s or at least 'break out' of php mode for outputting massive chunks of text like that.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the reason is because you are not getting the id again after the loop has finished. So when you recall `cp_share_fb_do()` for example the var `postid` is still set as the last id from the while loop. You will have to recall `get_the_ID()` or alternatively store the id in a var in each function eg

```
function cp_share_fb_do(){
  var id = '.get_the_ID().';
  jquery.ajax({ ///etc
```

just remember to make sure you change `post: postid` to the new var name.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've tried this: `function cp_share_gplus_do(){ var post'.get_the_ID().' = '.get_the_ID().';
 jQuery.ajax({dataType: "json", data: {action: "cp_share_gplus_do", post: post'.get_the_ID().'},` so each variable would be unique in theory. I also tried this: `function cp_share_gplus_do(){ var postid = '.get_the_ID().';
 jQuery.ajax({dataType: "json", data: {action: "cp_share_gplus_do", post: postid},` and it still pulls the last post ID that's on the home page instead of the first post that I'm sharing.

Comment: The issue must be with when you set the buttons then. I don't have much experience on the social net api side, but double check your `.get_the_title().` and `'.get_permalink().'`. Make sure you are getting the right id's in there. And that the ID is being passed within the while loop.